# Our role in the discussion at Meta.SE regarding the overall health and growth of SE sites

Tags: discussion

I just came across this question on meta.stackexchange: [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614)

Whats our say on that and how are we doing there?
From what I understand and they said,

> Now, communities can focus on Q&A about topics they love, not on whether their site will survive.

Thats very encouraging against something that Area51 keeps on displaying: *Needs work*, *Days in Beta* or something similar to that.

Comment: Yes, I think the jist is that they plan to keep sites in Beta indefinitely if they continue to be active but fail to grow to come out of Beta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

they also pinned down the criteria for coming out of Beta more firmly. An interesting point was:

> When a site starts to consistently receive **10 questions/day**, we’ll
>   consider it for graduation.

Unfortunately we're still well short

[image]

[We've had success in getting this up in the past](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/we-need-to-get-the-question-rate-up) but always in the short term and never by enough.

---

Interestingly the **answer rate** is the highest it's been since I've been on this site (at least 2 years). It's been slowly creeping up from 2 to about 2.5 for some time now, which is very positive.

[image]

Comment: I've never seen the questions above 3.3 but we've push right up to 2.8 over the past few days... So we'll see how it goes!

Comment: @Aravona We're at 3.7 today! Yay!

Comment: @Sue 4.1 this morning :)

Comment: @Aravona Yay!! I don't know if anyone who'll see this celebrates Thanksgiving, as it's an American holiday; but just in case, Happy Thanksgiving everyone!